# CSS - Multiple Segmented Controls Fail

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I've found a great segmented control over at http://www.prcvl.com/demos/segmented-controls and I'm now trying to adapt it to my needs.

Mhe problem is when I add multiple controls to the page clicking the buttons will ONLY affect the first segmented control.  Besides having to re-create the css/naming multiple times, does anyone know of another way to achieve this? Maybe by leveraging jquery?

Here is a fiddle of the exact code: http://jsfiddle.net/kyV5U/

Example:

```
<ul class="segmented-control">
    <li id="any"><a href="#any">Any</a></li>
    <li id="all"><a href="#all">All</a></li>
</ul>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>

<ul class="segmented-control">
    <li id="any"><a href="#any">Any 2</a></li>
    <li id="all"><a href="#all">All 2</a></li>
</ul>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It still only allows you to select from one of the segments.  Vs. being able to choose all of them

Comment: wait, do you want ALL of the buttons to be selected, or just the button in the control that was clicked? so if you clicked one of the "any" buttons, then all of the "any" buttons would be selected?

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the id and anchor tags of the subsequent controls.

```
<body>
 <ul class="segmented-control">
    <li id="any"><a href="#any">Any</a></li>
    <li id="all"><a href="#all">All</a></li>
 </ul>
 <div style="clear:both;"></div>

 <ul class="segmented-control">
    <li id="any2"><a href="#any2">Any 2</a></li>
    <li id="all2"><a href="#all2">All 2</a></li>
 </ul>

 <div style="clear:both;"></div>
 <ul class="segmented-control">
    <li id="any3"><a href="#any3">Any 3</a></li>
    <li id="all3"><a href="#all3">All 3</a></li>
 </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Makes sense, the only problem is it will deselect the other segments.

Comment: I don't think so because the styling is relying on the value passed in after the #. How would the page know which control you actually clicked just from the one value?

Comment: So I should leverage jquery most likely to accomplish this and set the .click element based on the parent UL - yes?

Comment: You could use javascript to toggle the state of one of those buttons, yes.